# AWUS051NH v2 not injecting in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I have an Alfa AWUS051NH v2 network card, and my Kali Linux recognizes it, however it won't inject packets when I run `aireplay-ng -9 wlan1mon`.

I have fully updated and upgraded Kali, but it still doesn't work.